# Iterative jQuery formatting JSON incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iteration

I have a JSON file with many nested objects which is structured similar to this:

```
    [
        {
            "name" : "Fruits",
            "subNav" :
            [
                {
                    "name" : "Apples",
                    "subNav" :
                    [
                        {
                            "name" : "Type 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "Type 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "Type 3"
                            "subNav" :
                            [
                                {
                                    "name" : "Type 3 A"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name" : "Type 3 B"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

This branching/nesting structure is quite extensive and has quite a few more 'key:value' pairs which I'm leaving out for the sake of readability.

I am attempting to create iterative jQuery/js which can go through the nested objects and format them into a nested list, here's that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json;
    $.getJSON( "megaNav.json", function( data ) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data , recurse);
        function recurse(key,val) {
            items.push( "<li class=''><a href=''>" + this.name + "</a></li>" );
            if (val instanceof Object) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty('subNav')){
                    items.push("<ul>");
                    $.each(this.subNav , recurse);
                    items.push("</ul>");
                }
            }
        };
        $('#section-nav').append(items);
    });
});
```

It works for reaching the depths of all the object branches, however rather than putting nested objects into nested ul's, it creates the ul,/ul pair and puts the next li on the same level as the previous like this:

```
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<ul></ul>
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<ul></ul>
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
```

Instead of like this (how it's supposed to be):

```
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<li><a>...etc</a></li>
<li>
    <a>...etc</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>...etc</a></li>
        <li><a>...etc</a></li>
        <li><a>...etc</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
Solved with the help of lyosef769's jsfiddle do he get's the answer! Here's what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/brLh8g5b/1/

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a `<ul>` to be a direct child of another `<ul>` anyway - they have to be inside an `<li>`.

Comment: Good point. But that doesn't really fix the jQuery problem...

Comment: are you sure? Have you tried adding a wrapper `<li>` in the case you detect a submenu?

Comment: Solved with the help of lyosef769's jsfiddle do he get's the answer! Here's what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/brLh8g5b/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling jQuery's `append` on an array of strings actually tries to add each string as a separate element.

So an array of `["<ul>","<li>..</li>","<li>..</li>","</ul>"]` will be translated to a `ul` element, followed by two `li` elements , and jQuery ignores the last tag, since it can't parse it.

You should call `$('#section-nav').append(items.join(""));`. That way jQuery will try to add the whole structure as a single string.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/brLh8g5b/

Comment: This is close to perfect! The only issue I just realized is I need the UL to be inside the LI above it, so in the case of the JSON everytime an object has a subNav, the UL should be inside that object

Comment: Solved with the help of your jsfiddle so you get the answer! Here's what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/brLh8g5b/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t79aLuec/

JAVASCRIPT

var tempData = [{
        "name": "Fruits",
            "subNav": [{
            "name": "Apples",
                "subNav": [{
                "name": "Type 1"
            }, {
                "name": "Type 2"
            }, {
                "name": "Type 3",
                    "subNav": [{
                    "name": "Type 3 A"
                }, {
                    "name": "Type 3 B"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }];

```
var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');

function createList($list, items) {
    items.forEach(function(item){
        var $li = $('<li>');
        $li.text(item.name);

        if (item.subNav) {
            $li.append('<ul></ul>');

            createList($li.find('ul'), item.subNav);
        }

        $list.append($li);
    });
}

createList($ul, tempData);
$('body').append($ul);
```